# Prime numbers $p$ and $q$ and possession of normal subgroup of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I have this following question from my class note on Sylow Theorem:

> Let $p$ and $q$ be prime numbers such that $p \nmid (q-1).$ Show that each group of order $pq$ possesses a normal subgroup of order $p.$

For that I know the followings:
(1) Group $G$ is *p*-group if there exists an integer $e$ such that $|G| = p^e,$ 
(2) A $p$-subgroup $H$ of $G$ is called *Sylow* *p*-subgroup of $G$ if $p \nmid |G/H|,$ and finally 
(3) A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is a Sylow *p*-subgroup if there exist integers $e$ and $m$ such that $|G| = p^em,$ and $(e, m) = 1,$ and also $|H| = p^e,$

but unfortunately I don't know how to assemble them to solve the problem. Any help would therefore be very much appreciated. Thank you for your time and help.

PS. If you have choices of elegant versus dummy down-to-earth solutions, do please give me the latter. I know it would be tedious for you but you have slowpoke turtle over here. Thank again for your patience.

Comment: Check example 5.14 of Milne's GT notes http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html

Comment: @janmarqz : Thanks for the pointer, I will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Sylow theorems, the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of the group is congruent to $1$ mod $p$ and divides the order of the group. Suppose $n=kp+1$ and $n\mid q$. Then since $q$ is prime we in fact have $kp+1=q$ or $k=0$. Assume $k\neq 0$. Then $q-1=kp$, meaning that $p\mid q-1$. Since we assume that this is not the case, we must have that $k=0$, hence the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups is $1$, and this Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal because all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate.

Comment: Thank you! Two questions though: (1) Based on the question only, how do you conclude using $p$ as the $p$ in $Syl_p (G)$? (2) I understand up to the point when you said $G$ has one normal subgroup (which is the $Syl_p (G)$,) but how do you go from there to conclude $|Syl_p (G)| = p$? (3) Thanks again and congratulation on earning PhD and also earning 7k reputation in just 2 months.

Comment: I don't understand question (1), please clarify. For (2), $G$ might have more than one normal subgroup, but it has exactly one Sylow $p$-subgroup using the argument in the answer using the third Sylow theorem. By the second Sylow theorem, there is exactly one Sylow $p$-subgroup if and only if the Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal. For (3), thanks.

Comment: Thanks as always. Let's forget (1) for the time being. For (2), let me make sure this is correct: The NUMBER of normal subgroup is different from the ORDER of normal subgroup, am I correct? But the question is asking for the ORDER, not the NUMBER. I hope I am not asking a dumb question here :-) Thanks again.

Comment: They are fixing the order of the subgroup as $p$. They want you to show there exists a normal subgroup with that order. Since the order of the group is $pq$, a subgroup of order $p$ is a Sylow subgroup. Therefore to show there is a normal such subgroup you have to show that there is exactly one.

Comment: I am still reading your comments... In the meantime I up-arrow the two comments you made.

Comment: Let me put my question this way: I read that Sylow's Theorem implies that if $G$ is finite, $G$ has at least one $Syl_p (G)$ iff $|Syl_p (G)| = p^e.$ Now we have established that there is indeed one $Syl_p (G),$ how do you go about proving that $e = 1$ such that $|Syl_p (G)| = p,$ such that the problem is solved? Thank you again.

Comment: @A.Magnus if the order of $G$ is $p^em$, where $p\nmid m$, then a Sylow $p$-subgroup is by definition a subgroup of size $p^e$. Thus a $p$-Sylow subgroup of a group of order $pq$ has order $p$.

Comment: Now I got them all. Thank you so much for your extreme patience. Happy holidays.